# Conda environment lost

Tags: python, environment, conda, miniconda

I had a previous installation of Python 2.7 and I still have all the related packages in `C:\Program Files\Anaconda`.
[image]

Some days ago I was not able to do conda update conda because there was a problem with the repositories. I solved that issue just installing miniconda. What I did not want is to overwrite my environment:

[image]

What should I do? Creating another environment and making it pointing to `C:\Program Files\Anaconda`? How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Miniconda and Anaconda are mostly the same thing with different default packages when you create new environments.

Your old Anaconda environments should still be available in *C:\Users\[username]\Anaconda\envs*, so try copying them from there to your new Miniconda installation's envs-folder in *C:\Users\[username]\Miniconda2\envs* and see if they show up when you write `conda info --envs`.

Comment: So I don't have a way to create a new environment connecting the old folder, right? I can just copy the old folder content in the Miniconda proper folder... right?

Comment: @AndreaIanni௫ I think copying the old environments is the easiest fix, but I haven't tested if it actually works. You could also just try uninstalling Miniconda and see if that allows you to use the old Anaconda install. If it doesn't you can always install Miniconda again.

Comment: This worked for me. I copied the environment folder from anaconda to miniconda, sourced it, and ran my code normally. It's not the most clean and elegant solution but it works.

Answer (score 4):

I offer this comment in the hopes it might assist any future reader wishing to avoid the same predicament.

Conda environments can be completely re-created from the rather small output of the `conda env export` command. Such outputs are often named *environment.yaml*, though this is merely a convention. I just created (with the command `conda create --name empty python=3.7`) a new environment. This is what `conda env export --name empty` spits out.

```
name: empty
channels:
  - http://conda.anaconda.org/holdenweb
  - anaconda-fusion
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - ca-certificates=2018.03.07=0
  - certifi=2018.8.24=py37_1
  - libcxx=4.0.1=h579ed51_0
  - libcxxabi=4.0.1=hebd6815_0
  - libedit=3.1.20170329=hb402a30_2
  - libffi=3.2.1=h475c297_4
  - ncurses=6.1=h0a44026_0
  - openssl=1.0.2p=h1de35cc_0
  - pip=10.0.1=py37_0
  - python=3.7.0=hc167b69_0
  - readline=7.0=h1de35cc_5
  - setuptools=40.2.0=py37_0
  - sqlite=3.24.0=ha441bb4_0
  - tk=8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - wheel=0.31.1=py37_0
  - xz=5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - zlib=1.2.11=hf3cbc9b_2
prefix: /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/empty
```

By saving this YAML file (perhaps in a Github repository or somewhere else safe from clumsy fingers) you can re-create the environment at any time with the commmand

```
conda env create -f path/to/YAML/file -n empty_copy
```

Exchanging YAML files is also a simple way to ensure that all members of a team are using equivalent environments. Exporting conda environments deals reasonably well with `pip`-installed packages, but there are some rough edges so stick to simple requirement specifications.

I apologise to the original questioner, for whom I understand this advice comes far too late. I presume because the answer was accepted the problem was solved!